# Using Grub on hard disk to boot live SD card

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, sd-card

I have a laptop running Ubuntu MATE 15.10, and said laptop has an internal media-card reader. I would like to be able to use that media-card reader to boot a liveCD installed on an SD card. Unfortunately, after much searching, I've been unable to find a way to do this. What makes this case special is:

1. My BIOS does not support booting from the SD card, so I need to find a workaround. Using my existing installation of GRUB2 to load a kernel, access the SD card, and boot would be my preferred method. Unfortunately,
2. Every guide I've found online to do this only describes how to boot to a drive that gets listed as an `sd*` device. My SD card reader lists as **mmcblk0** in my Ubuntu install.

So far, I have tried adding modules to my initramfs.img, modifying my `grub.cfg`, attempting a wide variety of methods for installing a LiveCD image on an SD card, and using the grub console. At the end of the day, however, I still have the same problem: **GRUB2 cannot see my mmcblk0 device**. I am certain that all I need is to get GRUB to load the appropriate modules/drivers, and see this device.I can handle it from there. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get there.

**EDIT:**

To try and clarify a bit, what I would like to be able to do is:

1. Insert a bootable SD card with GRUB installed
2. Turn on the machine and procede to the GRUB2 menu
3. Select a generic "SD Card" that will bring up the menu for the GRUB2 install on the SD card.
4. Boot

To do this, I believe that I need to:

1. Load a Linux kernel
2. Load the SD card drivers via said kernel
3. Use the GRUB2 'chainboot' feature to boot onto the SD card

I have a Linux kernel available to GRUB2 on the local machine, with the necessary drivers enabled. All I need to know is how to load the kernel, and how to use it to detect the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for because of the wording and because you SD card is mblk0

I got my Acer to boot from the SD card.
I simply used a USB live cd and it and chose the SD card.
You can choose "something else" and choose where to put the boot loader.
You want to put that on the root of the disk.  Do not choose a pm extension,  etc.

If your device allows legacy boot, then it is a piece of cake.
If your device only allows UEFI secure boot, then you have problems.  You need to make sure the Ubuntu trusted file is set in the bios after you installed.
Here you will need to set a password and then you can see the menu item to add a trusted source to the bios.  It will bring you to the directory where the file is.
Then change boot order on your bios.
As a test, I usually hit the boot order key when booting and see some choices.   I might find 0yes  and 1yes and Windows loader.
Try either of the yeses the number before the yes often seems to reflect the mblkid.

Lastly try boot-repair.
Boot-repair will also tell you a command to type in Windows admin cmom and window.

Good luck.
Remember legacy solves most problems.   You need to boot in the mode that you want to install.  If you want to install legacy, be in legacy mode before installing.  Visa versa.